# SimpleCaptcha image not loading (Can't mass-assign protected attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simplecaptcha

The problem is that the [simple_captcha](https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha) is not working properly. The captcha image is not showing. Please help.

#### controller.rb

```
if simple_captcha_valid?
  do something
else
  do something else
end
```

#### view.html.rb

```
<div class="captcha">
  <%= show_simple_captcha(label: "", placeholder: "", code_type: "numeric") %>   
</div>
```

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'simple_captcha2', require: 'simple_captcha'
```

#### Error

```
SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "simple_captcha_data".* FROM "simple_captcha_data" WHERE "simple_captcha_data"."key" = '******' ORDER BY "simple_captcha_data"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
**WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData: key**
```

Comment: Did you complete all steps which describe on github ?

Comment: Yes I did with no errors.

Comment: getting the same error. maybe when I bundle update.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem (with Rails 3). But resolve it by adding

## simple_captcha_gem_dir/lib/simple_captcha/simple_captcha_data.rb

```
attr_accessible :key, :value
```

where, in my case, **simple_captcha_gem_dir** is **~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/simple-captcha-2602bf19a63d**
(of course for production you can create a fork instead of edit local gem files)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution:

Put this in an initializer (`config/initializers/simple_captcha.rb`)

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  class SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_protected
  end
end
```

Thanks to [@zealot128](https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha/issues/7)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your call `<%= show_simple_captcha(:label => "", :placeholder => "", :code_type => "numeric") %>` it seems like you're using controller based implementation of simple_captcha

I don't see your `ApplicationController` code but make sure the following lines are present in `app/controllers/application.rb`

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers
end
```

**UPDATE** Model's Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  apply_simple_captcha
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  apply_simple_captcha :message => "The secret Image and code were different", :add_to_base => true
end
```

Comment: In which model? And what to add.
attr_accessible :[what to write here] and where to write this line, in which model.

Comment: I thought you were using Rails 3 version and suggested to add `attr_accessible` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model. But, seems like you're migrated to Rails 4. It would be great if you could share the model. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes the include part is there. Suppose I am implementing captcha for user signup then, where to add attr_accessible, (in user model or any else model). Thank you.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE in the answer. Are you using Rails 3 or 4? `attr_accessible` is no longer required in Rails 4 as the strong params were introduced.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.1.2
I used the config below in simple_captcha.rb

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  class SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_protected :captcha, :captcha_key
  end
end
```

but...
As I noticed in simple captcha controller in `.rvm/gems/bundler`, captcha key/value is passed via params[:captcha_key] and params[:captcha] which impose the problem because in view I used

```
<%= f.simple_captcha :label => "Enter numbers.." %>
```

in which params are passed via `params[:MODEL][:captcha]`

so...
for now I just added a set_captcha action in controller to set

```
params[:captcha] = params[:MODEL][:captcha]
params[:captcha_key] = params[:MODEL][:captcha_key]
```

I'm looking for a better solution, any idea?